# Code repetition in Swift

Tags: swift, accelerate-framework

I have a generic storage class:

```
class Storage<T> {
  var storage: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>
  var size: Int32

  init(_ size: Int) {
    self.size = Int32(size)
    self.storage = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.allocate(capacity: size)
  }
}
```

I want to extend it to be able to have different mathematical functions. For instance if I want to have sine function for `Float` storage:

```
import Accelerate

extension Storage where T == Float {
  // In-place sine function.
  func sin() {
    vvsinf(storage, storage, &size)
  }
}
```

or in case of `Double` storage:

```
import Accelerate

extension Storage where T == Double {
  // In-place sine function.
  func sin() {
    vvsin(storage, storage, &size)
  }
}
```

The only difference between these two implementations are names of functions used (`vvsinf` and `vvsin`). And if we want to extend storage by adding more math functions like this, we going to copy-paste our code for every function in two places. If additionally we need to support copy (instead of in-place) math operations, number of places we need to repeat our code becomes 4.

My question is:

Is it possible to avoid code repetition described above in Swift?
In case with C, it could be easily done using macros.

Comment: I would suggest to check the [`Numeric`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric) Protocol.

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 4, the inheritance structure of numbers is much cleaner. Have a look at the finer details here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0104-improved-integers.md

As far as the code is concerned:

```
extension Storage where T: Numeric
{
    func sin()
    {
        vvsinf(storage, storage, &size)
    }
}
```

This will cover you for `Float`, `Double`, `Int`, `UInt`, and all the others I've likely forgot.

Comment: The problem in your implementation is that `vvsinf ` can be only used for `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>`. For `Double` we have `vvsin` function. There's no sine for integer types.

Comment: I see. In which case, you could potentially cast to an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>` and just use one `vvsin` implementation for either `Float` or `Double`. To be honest, given that you only need to handle two types, I'd just stick with the repetition for `sin`. You can still make an extension using `Numeric` for any functions that don't have specific low level methods to call.